# Using arrayfun to solve a equation system (with vpasolve) MatLab

Tags: matlab, system, equation, symbolic-math

I am struggling with solving a problem as efficient as possible.

I have two equations and want to solve them together. Furthermore, I want to solve them for four different cases. I can solve them independently altering the code for each case. I can also solve them by accessing a vector that contains the desired value for one of them (e.g., the first value of `A`) by using `arrayfun`. However I can't manage to do all of them together.

My code:

```
clc
clear all
close all

% scalar parameters 
g = 9.807;                      % Gravity constant, m/s2
d = 1.225;                      % Density of air, kg/m3
x = 1000;                       % Height, m

% vector parameters
%t  = 0:2:10;                    % time, seconds
A  = [1.2; 1.7; 1.8; 0.3];      % Area, m^2
m  = [82; 84; 90; 25];          % Mass, kg 
Cd = [0.3; 1.14; 0.29; 0.045];  % Drag coefficient, -

syms v t
eqn1  = 2*m./(A.*Cd*d).* log(abs(cosh(t.*sqrt(A.*Cd*d*g./(2*m))))) == x;
eqn2  = (2*g*m./(d*A.*Cd)).*tanh(t.* sqrt((g*d*Cd.*A)./(2*m))) - v == 0;
  
eqns=[eqn1 eqn2];
variables = [v t];
result = arrayfun(@vpasolve, eqns, 'uniform', 0)

%disp('v='),disp(eval(v)); 
%disp('t='),disp(eval(t));
```

I get a result for `t` (which is weirdly negative and I don't know why), but I only get a {1×1 struct} for `v`, which I don't want. I know I can solve this also by using a `for` loop, but I wanted to make it more efficient.

I tried the code written above and solved it in various forms, however not as desired.

Comment: For what it’s worth, `arrayfun` isn’t really more efficient than a `for` loop. MATLAB doesn’t accelerate `arrayfun` the way it does element-wise array operations.

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it implemented you're effectively trying to solve four equations with two unknowns, which isn't supported by `vpasolve` except in the case of polynomial systems.

It looks like you're trying to solve the same system for four different combinations of values for the parameters `A`, `m`, and `Cd`. The easiest way to do that is to just break this out as a `for` loop (there is simply no benefit to using `arrayfun` here – speed or otherwise). You'll need to create some temporary symbolic variable for the parameter (there are a few ways this could be done). Here is example code to do just that:

```
% scalar parameters 
g = 9.807;                      % Gravity constant, m/s2
d = 1.225;                      % Density of air, kg/m3
x = 1000;                       % Height, m

% vector parameters
%t  = 0:2:10;                   % time, seconds
A  = [1.2; 1.7; 1.8; 0.3];      % Area, m^2
m  = [82; 84; 90; 25];          % Mass, kg 
Cd = [0.3; 1.14; 0.29; 0.045];  % Drag coefficient, -

syms v t real
syms A_sym m_sym Cd_sym real    % Temporary symbolic variables

eqn1  = 2*m_sym./(A_sym.*Cd_sym*d).* log(abs(cosh(t.*sqrt(A_sym.*Cd_sym*d*g./(2*m_sym))))) == x;
eqn2  = (2*g*m_sym./(d*A_sym.*Cd_sym)).*tanh(t.* sqrt((g*d*Cd_sym.*A_sym)./(2*m_sym))) - v == 0;

eqns=[eqn1 eqn2];
variables = [v t];

n = length(A);      % Number of prameter sets
result = cell(n,1); % Preallocate resultant cell array
for i = 1:n
    % Substitute in numeric values for i-th parameter set
    eqns_sub = subs(eqns,{A_sym,m_sym,Cd_sym},{A(i),m(i),Cd(i)});
    
    % Solve and store in cell array
    result{i} = vpasolve(eqns_sub,variables);
end
```

The output, `result`, is a 4-by-1 cell array of structs with your two variables, `v` and `t`, as VPA-valued fields for each.

You could replace the last few lines with the following if what you want is a numeric array as the output (this assumes that only one solution is found for each parameter set):

```
n = length(A);                          % Number of prameter sets
result = zeros(n,length(variables));    % Preallocate resultant array
for i = 1:n
    % Substitute in numeric values for i-th parameter set
    eqns_sub = subs(eqns,{A_sym,m_sym,Cd_sym},{A(i),m(i),Cd(i)});
    
    % Solve, convert to double precision, and store in array
    out = vpasolve(eqns_sub,variables);
    result(i,:) = double([out.v out.t]);
end
```